# syslog is printing only few logs

Tags: c, logging, syslog

my rsyslog.conf file

```
local6.*        /var/log/X.log;RSYSLOG_FileFormat
local5.*        /var/log/Y.log;RSYSLOG_FileFormat
```

C program is having two different openlog for writing in two different files.

```
/* openlog() opens a connection to the system logger for a program. */
    openlog("pluto", LOG_CONS | LOG_NDELAY | LOG_PID, LOG_LOCAL5);
    openlog("pluto", LOG_CONS | LOG_NDELAY | LOG_PID, LOG_LOCAL6);
```

while printing log using,

```
syslog(LOG_DEBUG | LOG_LOCAL6,"X");
syslog(LOG_DEBUG | LOG_LOCAL5,"Y");
```

syslog is behaving differently it is printing only few logs. The same code is working fine in other machines. Is there any machine dependencies ?

Comment: Syslog is circular buffer, you need to increase the limit if you see partial logs.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer,  syslog outputs to a log file and/or the console and/or stderr.  It is not a circular buffer kept in memory.

Comment: What parameters were used in the call to: `setlogmask ();`?

Comment: on linux 16.04 the man page for `syslog()` says nothing about a `rsyslog.conf` file

Comment: @user3629249 I'm not using setlogmask ()

Comment: @LethalProgrammer, Thanks for reply.
other programs (which are using syslog) are able to log everything only one program is behaving differently.

Comment: @user3629249 I'm using syslog on CentOS